# CN1Cordova Plugin on IOS Advertising not working

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, codenameone

I using cordova plugin (https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) to send Advertising.

On Android works fine, but on IOS advertising not working.

No errors on log. I'm lost.
This is my Json Parameters to startAdvertising funcion. (https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#startadvertising)

```
    {
    "timeout":1000,
    "connectable":false,
    "includeDeviceName":false,
    "includeTxPowerLevel":false,
    "name":"IAP",
    "manufacturerId":42598,
    "manufacturerSpecificData":"3bX+OJzUg8Q=",
    "services":["A66A"]
    }
```

On calling isAdvertising funcion response with false.

```
    por omisión 20:18:41.097965+0100    App Command created      isAdvertising BluetoothLePlugin isAdvertising
    por omisión 20:18:41.098278+0100    App Firing selector isAdvertising:
    por omisión 20:18:41.098584+0100    App Result {"isAdvertising":false}
```

Comment: Advertising doesn't seem to be an API we support in the cn1lib. Looking at the code it seems that you need to include both service and services but that's only a guess. They specifically mention the difference between iOS and Android

Comment: Thanks Shai, you are right, I added this funtionallity to the lib, it works fine for Android, but not in iOS. I tried adding the service, (modified the lib too), but do not works, I am lost and sad. Regards

Comment: Can you show the source you added? Submit a PR to the core lib?

Comment: Hi Shai, what is a PR and how can I submit it to the core lib?

Comment: It's a pull request in github. I assume you created a fork of our project in github, you can submit the changes back from that fork to the mainline using the pull request button.

Comment: Hi Shai, I uploaded my code here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ii879uv08umbhrl/test.zip?dl=0 I don't be able to send advertising on IOS, on Android works fine.

Comment: Can you at least file an issue so we'll have tracking of the authorship here. Attach the change to the issue so we have source origin of the code. This is important in case we get a licensing issue we need to be able to track changes and know where we got them from. This discussion isn't something that would be easily found and a dropbox link can disappear suddenly.

Comment: Ok Shai, I created this issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3383 Thanks for your help